# Wrong charset in form in Vue JS inline template

Tags: templates, vue.js, character-encoding

I have just started using Vue JS. I made a small project for a customer, but I ran into some problems with character encoding in a form for sending queries to the customer. I've created some simple inline templates, one of which includes a form. When submitting this form, the character encoding is wrong - Æ Ø Å / æ ø å isn't diplayed correctly.

The setup is fairly simple. I have the html page with vue / js scripts and a php script for sending the email. The php script works fine without vue - that is, the character encoding is working fine. But using it with vue causes these character encoding problems.

1. When using vue - the email script sends the email, but the character encoding is messed up.
2. When using the php script WITHOUT vue - the email is sent and the character encoding is just fine.

Any ideas, references - well, just about anything would be helpfull now :)

Comment: save vuejs and html files as utf-8 encoding

Comment: I'm not sure, what you are referring to here ? The meta charset ? I already did that :)

Comment: No! Take a look at this : https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding

Comment: Thanks - I'll see if I can find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So minor glitch happening there. Apparently the php script didn't work as planned. I was using iso instead of utf-8 :) Apparently using vue / vue-router (with inline templates) with a php script for sending mails requires one to use utf-8 and not iso.